# Run specific script after every Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-7, scripting, automation, windows-update

Is there a way to run a specific script each time Windows update completes (i.e., after reboot or after an update that doesn't require a reboot)?

My application is suffering from [MSCOMCTL.OCX updates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597986/en-us), and it seems that every time Windows Update updates, the user is required to apply my fixup script.

**EDIT**: For Windows 7 and later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe, ultimately, the correct answer is "Fix your application".  However, you may not be able to for any number of reasons.  That being said...

---

Which version of Windows?  In Vista/2008 and up, you can tie Scheduled Tasks to specific Event IDs.  In the System event log, Event ID 19 from WindowsUpdateClient, indicates [successful WUA Update Installation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735630(v=ws.10).aspx).

[image: Event Viewer WindowsUpdateClient Event ID 19]

Launch the Task Scheduler snap-in, `taskschd.msc`.  Right click the "Task Scheduler Library" and select "Create Basic Task...".

[image: Create Basic Task]

In the next screen, input a name and a brief description and click "Next".

[image: Generic name and description]

Click the radio button labeled "When a specific event is logged", click "Next".

[image: When a specific event is logged]

Select "System" as the log, "WindowsUpdateClient" as the source and "19" as Event ID, click "Next".

[image: Log source and event ID]

Click the "Start a program" radio button, click "Next".

[image: Start a program]

Provide the path to your "fix it" script or executable, click "Next".

[image: path to script]

Review your settings are correct, then click "Finish".

[image]

You will now see the Scheduled Task listed in the library with your settings.

---

Here is a command line example using only `C:\Windows\system32\schtasks.exe`, the XPath filter syntax took me a while.  It appears the Task Scheduler [uses only a subset of XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231312.aspx).

```
REM Create scheduled task triggered by WindowsUpdateClient event ID 19
schtasks /Create /TN "Post WUA Update Install" /TR "C:\scripts\your.fix.cmd" /SC ONEVENT /EC System /MO "*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'] and (EventID=19)]]"
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! Will I be able to use [task scheduler scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607(v=vs.85).aspx) to automate the setup?

Comment: I'm out and about right now, but yeah, [`schtasks.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx) supports `ONEVENT` so you should be able to... I may knock together a Powershell example if I get the time.  Note that Group Policy Preference Client Side Extensions also allow for creating Scheduled Tasks.

Comment: @krlmlr I've added a simple command line example which you should be able to utilize in your automations.